# How does AMD differ from CommonJS?

Tags: javascript

Both of them are encapsulation techniques for Javascript, but what why would somebody choose one over the other?

In what situations should be AMD or CommonJS be used over the other?

Comment: Main thing: Asyncronous vs syncronous. Note: If using a build script to merge everything, this is rather irrelevant.